# Programmatically modifications will not apply to children class (viewController)

Tags: ios, swift

I my iOS application maybe I need to override some **viewControllers** so I developed the following method to discover if the override *ViewController* exists I use it otherwise use from the original *viewController*.

```
internal class func getOverride<T: RBaseViewController>(id: String, mClass: AnyClass) -> T
{
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: RConstants.Static.MAIN_STORYBOARD_NAME, bundle: nil)
    let originalViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(id) as! T

    var className = NSStringFromClass(mClass)

    // Removing the prefix of class name if exists
    if let index: String.Index = className.rangeOfString(".")?.startIndex.successor()
    {
        className = className.substringFromIndex(index)
    }

    // Override class name
    var overrideClassName = className! + RConstants.Static.CLASSES_OVERRIDE_SUFFIX

    if let mClass: AnyClass = NSClassFromString(overrideClassName)
    {
        RLog.debug("View controller override found")
        // ViewController is overrode
        if let overeideClass: T.Type = mClass as? T.Type
        {
            // Create instance and return
            let overrodeViewController = overeideClass()

            let view = originalViewController.view
            originalViewController.view = nil
            overrodeViewController.view = view

            return overrodeViewController
        }
    }

    return originalViewController
}
```

The Override viewController **extends** from the original one and just maybe some methods will change.

But the issue is that the modifications that I applied on the viewController is not affecting the overrode viewController.

For example in the parent viewController class I have the following code :

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    title = "Map"
}
```

But in the Child viewController the title is **empty**, This issue is not just for **title**, **Anything** that is changed in the main viewController **programmatically** will not affect the child viewController.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Humour me, if you try printing "Hello world" in your RBaseViewController class, does it print the string?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Yes, I tested it now, Printed it.

Comment: From where, and when do you call getOverride? What controller (or other object) is that method in?

Comment: @rdelmar in the parent ViewController I have a method, the name of it is getInstance() in this method I call the getOverride then return it. And everywhere that I want access parent ViewController , I call `ParentVeiwController.getInstance()`

Comment: Is the child view controller written as a subclass of the parent (wrong thing to call it, since a parent is something else in Cocoa) view controller? Or are you expecting it to become a subclass with the code shown above?

Comment: @DaveBatton the subclass definition is like this : `@objc(ViewControllerOverride)
class ViewControllerOverride: ViewController`

Comment: Switching a view controller out from a storyboard at runtime seems like the wrong approach to me. That's just not something you do. But if you insist, I'd guess that you need to make the overrodeViewController property a class property. Something needs to retain it. The view doesn't retain its view controller, and the code above isn't retaining it.

Comment: @DaveBatton I changed `overrodeViewController`  to a class property, But nothing changed

Comment: I guess, The issue is with the view, Because the view of subclass viewController is a copy of supperClass view, Is not the same, So the modification is not applying on it.

Comment: I think the problem is that any changes you make to the parent view, are made in the instance that you have on screen. With this line, ` let originalViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(id) as! T` you are creating a new instance that never appears on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

By using `xib`files instead of `storyboards` this issue has fixed.

Seems that this is not possible to change the controller of a storyboard view.

in The above question, When I had set the view of originalViewController to nil all and set the new view to overrode view controller so the new view is not the same as old one, It's just a copy of it, So all the modifications shouldn't apply on the copy of it.